# How can I publish my react native, native modules and native component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, publish

I created both android and ios bridge of an SDK to use in my React native project. I have two  native modules and a native component folder for both ios and android. Question is i want to publish these bridges for the community but how am I gonna do it. I researched and find react-native-builder-bob but I have no clue what should I do with it.

I created a test library with Builder bob, but I didn't quite understand what to do. Also, do I need to create two separate libraries for native modules and native components?